# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting a dynamically resizing `Total` Row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditional format a dynamically resizing `Total` row of multiple tables stacked one above the other. The number of cells in the `Total` row may change depending upon the selection in a `Year` dropdown.

```
A  |   B   |   C    |    D    |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H    |    I    |   J   |  K  |  L  | M  |
           <Year dropdown>

   |Issues|2020-Jan|2020-Feb|2020-Mar|2020-Apr|2020-May|2020-Jun|  |  |  |  |  |  |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | abc  | 9      |    2   | 2      | 1      | 3      | 8      |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   | def  | 1      |    3   | 7      | 1      | 5      | 3      |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   | ghi  | 2      |    1   | 3      | 1      | 1      | 2      |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |Total | 12     |    6   | 12     |  3     | 9      | 13     |  |  |  |  |  |  |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using this formula to highlight the Total row. However, it is highlighting the entire row depending upon what range is set in the Conditional Formatting > `Apply to Range` box. I want to highlight only the numeric cells i.e. exclude blank cells.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("total",$B1))
```

This highlights the entire Total row including any blank cells. I modified it to exclude any blank cells in row, but no joy!

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("total",$B1)), SEARCH("total",$B1)<>""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula:

```
=(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("total",$B1))+(($B1:$Z1<>"")))>1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this, relying on relative addressing to modify the formula as it's effectively dragged across the formatted area:

```
=and(isnumber(search("Total",$B3)),B3<>"")
```

[image]